# django rest api FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'i' into field

Tags: python, django, rest, api

i am facing this weird issue in django "FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'i' into field". i am tying to find the problems for hour . below is my model

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
def code_generate():
    while 1:
        from django.conf import settings
        import random, string
        code = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(6))
        try:
            Users.objects.get(id=code)
        except:
            return code

class Users(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table='users'
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, default=code_generate, max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    creation_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Login(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

i received this error upon calling serializer.is_valid

> "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
>   django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'i' into field. Choice
>   s are: creation_timestamp, email, id, mobile, name, password, username

Comment: Probably have a typo somewhere and instead of `id` you have `i`?

Comment: Have you printed the faulty record?  Catch the exception and dump the useful variable values.

Comment: You need to actually show the serializer, and the view where you are calling its is_valid method.

Comment: You shouldn't be using reserved 'id' as a name, for starters. Now, any number of minor syntax errors in your model might cause such a problem. It wasn't until I used 'manage.py check' that I found a problem with my model's ordering in Meta that caused this for me, and fixing that issue solved my problem. So see if the admin check function gives you a hint?